# Passing HardwareSerial and SoftwareSerial as a Class Property

Tags: serial, softwareserial, class

I wish to know if there is a way to use a single property `Serial0` to hold a `HardwareSerial` or a `SoftwareSerial` or other class instances supporting basic methods such as `available()`, `read()` and `write()`, in order to make a `CustomSerial` Class (*polymorphism*?).

```
class CustomSerial{
    <GenericSerial??> Serial0;
    char c;
    void read(void){
        c=Serial0.read();
    }
};
```

The calls should be:

```
CustomSerial SerialCus;
int n=SerialCus.available();
char c=SerialCus.read();
SerialCus.write(c);
```

What should I use as `GenericSerial` class, or what should be the proper use? I tried the `Stream` class (as the answer pointed), but for some reason the functionality is not preserved (it writes unknown characters). Should indeed `Stream` be the generic class I need for this?

Comment: If you can not make a common class, then you can use a template. If the class (any class) has a .available() and .read() and .write(), then the compiler fills in the used class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base type for Arduino hardware serial classes, SoftwareSerial and other software serial classes and some other Arduino classes is [Stream (reference)](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/stream/). [Stream.h on GitHub](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Stream.h)

[image]

```
class CustomSerial {

private:
  Stream &stream;

public:
  CustomSerial(Stream &_stream) : stream(_stream) {}

  int read() {
    return stream.read();
  }

  int available() {
    return stream.available();
  }

  int peek() {
    return stream.peek();
  }

  void write(byte b) {
    stream.write(b);
  }

};

SoftwareSerial Serial0(10, 11);
CustomSerial SerialCus(Serial0);

void setup() {
}

void loop(){
  if (SerialCus.available()) {
    char c = SerialCus.read();
    SerialCus.write(c);
  }
}
```

Comment: I indeed used `Stream` for defining the property, but for some reason, this do not work the same way as using `HardwareSerial`, hence i have been unable to extend it for `SoftwareSerial` instances.

Comment: @hyprfrcb, I added code to the answer

Comment: This setting works perfect!... And also address how to use the `Stream` references... :)

Comment: The AltSoftSerial uses the `Stream` as well.